# How do I manage several views in angular.js

Tags: angularjs

I have the following page layout:

[image: Diagram]

1. is the main menu
2. is the top menu
3. is the content [EDIT: Whoops it seems that I've lost some numbering, section 3 is the large middle section :)]

I would like to have separate sections to be managed (handled) by a separate modules (which seems logical), so how do I do that if I have only one `ng-view` that does handling of whole page view. How does one bind a module to a separate ui section?

Thank you in advance

Comment: you can use ng-controller attribute in html.

Comment: ok, I see, but then how can I use routing, each section may have... Say 5 states, how is it possible for each controller to extract it's parameter from route?

Comment: btw, can I use controllers in conjunction with ng-view, i.e. to have a controller defined inside ng-view?

Comment: you can use controllers wherever you want. also could you please, explain what exactly you need. I don't get your first comment.

Comment: MainMenu has menu items, by selecting some menu item we change state of whole MainMenu, the same for the top menu, the content section may also have `state`s. Is it possible to use routing and deep linking, for keeping the overal state of the application?

Comment: you can inject $routeParams to your controller for that. see: http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.$routeParams

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is something many people want to accomplish with standard angular router but doesn't work well without hackish attempts. That is why Angular-UI team is working on a more refined solution to the nested states problem.

Checkout the [ui-router module](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router). Make sure to read [the docs](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki) carefuly and checkout [the sample app](http://angular-ui.github.io/ui-router/sample/#/) as it may be a little confusing at first.

Answer (score 7):

Define your main menu and top menu as directives and only the main content as the ng-view container.
A directive has a dedicated template and controller and helps to achieve code modularity.